# Should you close the process' previous Window Station handle after a new one is set?

Tags: winapi

In the documentation for the [`CloseWindowStation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-closewindowstation) function, it says:

> Do not specify the handle returned by the [`GetProcessWindowStation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getprocesswindowstation) function.

But, what are you supposed to do if you get the process' window station handle and then set a new one after, using [`SetProcessWindowStation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocesswindowstation)? Should you close the one you retrieved, or should both handles stay open?

```cpp
HWINSTA oldWinSta = GetProcessWindowStation();

HWINSTA newWinSta = CreateWindowStation(...);

SetProcessWindowStation(newWinSta);

// should you do this?
// sins now GetProcessWindowStation would return newWinSta instead of oldWinSta
// or should both stay open?
CloseWindowStation(oldWinSta);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must not close handle returned by `GetProcessWindowStation` function, this is directly stated. This API not create a **new** handle but return an **existing** (we can simply check this by calling an API 2 times - the same handle value will be returned). Because of this, you don't need to close this handle, system manages it by itself. If you set another window station for process - system will close the old one by itself. After a successful call to `SetProcessWindowStation(newWinSta)` your `oldWinSta` is already closed. When you try to call `CloseWindowStation(oldWinSta)` again, it will return `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE` until the handle is reoccupied by other window station; in that case, it will be closed.